# How do serializers know when a class has to be considered "primitive"?

Tags: java, serialization, reflection

Let's take for example `jackson serializer` and say we have a class like this:

```
public class Car {
    private String brand;
    private Integer weight;
}
```

If we serialize this we'll get for example:

```
{
    "brand": "Fiat",        
    "weight": 50
}
```

But how did it know that String is not an object composed of different primitive values? I mean it has properties inside, and so does the Integer class.
Then why did it not serialize like this?

```
{
    "brand": {
        "value": [  // primitive char[] inside String
            "F",
            "i",
            "a",
            "t",
        ],
        "hash": xxx // primitive int inside String
    }       
    "weight": {
        "value": 50 // primitive int inside Integer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, you'll have logic like this at the heart of libraries that do serialization:

```
public String serializeValue(Object ob) {
    if (ob == null) {
       return NULL_REPRESENTATION;
    } else if (ob.getClass() == String.class) {
       return ob.toString();
    } else if (ob.getClass() == Integer.class) {
       return ob.toString();
    } else if (ob instanceof List) {
       return serializeArray( ((List)ob).toArray());
    } ...
    else {
       return serializeFieldsWithReflection(ob);
    }
}
```

In reality you'll never see it exactly like this, because this is a pretty bad way of organising your code, I only wrote it this way to demonstrate the basic idea.

Instead there will be a bunch of pluggable serializers: one for each special case the library provides custom serialisation for (strings, numbers, dates, lists, maps, enums), and one "generic" serializer, that just iterates through all the (non-transient) fields.

This mechanism usually also allows you to plug in your own special serializers for your custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

jackson-databind module constructs BeanPropertyWriter instances for each serialized object's property. If it's underlying JavaType doesn't represent a primitive - which can be easily serialized using toString(), it serializes the property as an object, array, map or whatever feasible.

Check out the classes extending **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer**